# Is the in flight emergency manual of a Boeing 737 Max 8 available to read online?

Tags: boeing-737, emergency-procedures

I frequently read about pilots going through manuals/checklists/procedures  in an emergency situation in an airliner while in flight. Is there an online resource where the public can actually read it, for e.g. for Boeing 737 Max 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *in flight emergency manual* is called the **Quick Reference Handbook (QRH)** and is in general not made publicly available by the manufacturer or airlines.

It is however possible to find quite a few online. Pages like [smartcockpit.com](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircrafts-models.html) have a lot of resources available. The Boeing 737 MAX is not mentioned on their page. A Google [search](https://www.google.de/search?q=737%20max%20qrh) for "737 max qrh" may help you find something.